# Node, Mongoose: Remove json element from query result with delete

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I get this strange behavior. Here's the thing: I make a database query and want to delete an element of the json returned by the query. So this doesn't seem to work (i.e. the element is not deleted),

```
var user=json;
delete user.element;
```

while this works

```
var user={element:json.element,blement:'stuff'}
delete user.element;
```

Comment: Is the DB result JSON or a JS object? You may have to `JSON.parse()` the result, prior to accessing it like an object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what you are referring to as JSON is actually a Mongoose document object given the tags you added to your question. Since that object is attached to it's "schema", you may have rules in there such as a "required" field or such that are interfering with the operation you are trying to do.

In order to get a raw form of the Object back, simply use the `.toObject()` method on the document result:

```
Model.findOne({ _id: id}, function(err,doc) {

    var raw = doc.toObject();
    delete raw.element;

    console.log( raw );

});
```

Of course you can always just omit the field from being returned in the query result with the basic form provided by [`.select()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-select):

```
Model.findOne({ _id: id}, '-element', function(err,doc) {

    console.log( doc );

});
```

Either form would remove that particular field from the response, but if you possibly want more control over the result than what can be provided by the field projection from [`.select()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-select) then use the `.toObject()` form and manipulate just as a plain JavaScript object.

Comment: thanks! I always thought that findOne returns a JSON, which also explaines some other issues I had...